# Api call from a virtualhost returns 404 apache reverse proxy

Tags: spring-boot, apache, reverse-proxy, react-tsx

I'm trying to run a react typescript application and a springboot application on virtualhosts with apache reverse proxy to make them run on the same localhost, basically i want them to run on the same port so that i can retrive the jsession id when i make the backend call for the login using basic spring security in backend and axios for the call in frontend, if i try to run both apps the call at the api login returns 404 but if I remove the virtual host of react the and i try a postman call on the port it goes smooth but as soon as i try to run both virtual hosts i still get 404

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ProxyPass /be http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /be http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

this is the config file , i've abilitated modules and virtual host in the config file, i've already forwarded headers in the application.properties of my backend

EDIT: I have changed the config file to give a name to the backend, now when calling api as http://localhost/be i get a 403 error in postman

Comment: Which of the identical virtual hosts do you expect to get hit? You've mapped `*:81` for both, without giving a server name or other identifying information. This can not work.

Comment: Yeah still new to this, trying to figure out things. I changed something and now i can reach the endpoint but i get 403 error now on the postman call

Comment: You should  have both of the ProxyPass instructions in the same virtual host. I guess that order matters, so I'd put the `/be` variant to the top.

Comment: Putting both apps in the same virtual host does not solve the problem